# How to set up HBase in AWS?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hbase, amazon-emr

I need to set up HBase remotely and since, I have a trial 12 months AWS account, I chose to do it in AWS.

This document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hbase-create.html describes the initial steps but it's not enough.

Could you explain me how to set up HBase in AWS properly in order to connect to it with my Java application? (how to expose port, enable inbound/outbound traffic, etc.)

Comment: Are you planning on installing it on EC2 instance or EMR cluster.If it is EMR then it is already there as one of the application.

Comment: On EMR cluster. I’m able to create a cluster using steps from the link but don’t know what to do further